# Docker Notary no trust data available

Tags: json, ssl, docker

I'm new to Docker Notary and require a server to be setup for my research work. The issue with this is I am using a self-signed certificate, already overwritten the default `root-ca.crt`, `notary-signer.crt` and `notary-server.crt`.

Openssl validates the certificate correctly, as can be seen from the output:

```
subject=/C=SG/ST=Some-State/O=<value>/OU=DCT/CN=<Amazon EC2 hostname>/emailAddress=<value>
issuer=/C=SG/ST=Some-State/O=<value>/OU=DCT/CN=<Amazon EC2 hostname>/emailAddress=<value>

No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA384
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits

SSL handshake has read 2348 bytes and written 431 bytes

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Session-ID: 398FCDC32B644161D9243A25AA4E001408874E93247427609CD95E6EF8F83761
Session-ID-ctx: 
Master-Key: 5427F024069D898563712EA826F2DF1582E8383F63FB13E9F6C6B6CAF1C4DC0A027942679426341F889F2E9DB0062C1D
Key-Arg   : None
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
TLS session ticket:
0000 - bc e4 fe 83 82 a1 1b 96-44 f7 1d 0c 9e 6f 45 8d   ........D....oE.
0010 - 93 1e 5a c2 8c 9f 72 db-f6 45 4a 86 69 fe 30 20   ..Z...r..EJ.i.0 
0020 - 98 9f 08 3d f5 bd ad d5-65 df 48 58 e4 6c f9 06   ...=....e.HX.l..
0030 - b6 28 e7 df 03 04 ac ad-ea 87 2c d8 db 64 73 44   .(........,..dsD
0040 - 0a b7 26 fe 2f a7 39 9c-5d 25 ca 21 68 76 37 26   ..&./.9.]%.!hv7&
0050 - 5e 0b d7 ea be 97 ea c8-16 b6 b0 04 30 13 0d 1e   ^...........0...
0060 - 01 98 5e cf a1 58 61 df-30 14 d8 a6 f5 c0 7b 85   ..^..Xa.0.....{.
0070 - 11 cb 4c 73 93 e3 1e 53-                          ..Ls...S

Start Time: 1494736027
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

400 Bad Requestclosed
```

I have also edited `server-config.json` to reflect the certificate algorithm to RSA and edited `config.json` in `cmd/notary` to point to my hostname:4443.

The issue is that after i rebuild docker notary and run the command

```
notary -s https://<server hostname>:4443 -d ~/.docker/trust list docker.io/library
```

I get this result

```
* fatal: no trust data available
```

I find it frustrating that for the last 2 days I have been pondering over this and the documentation is not very clear on how to do it either (probably because it is not even in stable yet).

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: I have also set 

export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST_SERVER=https://<hostname>

Comment: Sorry I can't help, I find Notary to be a poorly-documented black hole of despair.

Comment: I feel the same way, but I have no choice but to get it up for my research work.